# sql statement not updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following php code that is supposed to connect to the database and update some info.  However it is not updating.  It doesnt give any errors, it connects just fine... the sql statement just doesnt seem to be working but everything looks ok to me.

```
 if ($send != "no") {            
                $db_name = "auctionfinal";
                $table_name = "auctions";
                $connection = @mysql_connect("auctionfinal.db.6084638.hostedresource.com", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die(mysql_error());
                $db = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

                $sql = "UPDATE $table_name SET curbid = '$_POST[price]', nbids = '$totalnbid' WHERE aucname = '$auc' ";

                $result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

                if ($result) {
                    echo "Thank you! You have bid on the auction for $auc, the current bid is $curbid, there have been $nbids bids on this auction so far.";
                }
            } else if ($send == "no") {
                echo "$user_err";
            }
```

Comment: For starters, remove '@' from all those function calls so you can see any errors.

Comment: [Bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) sends regards.

Comment: even without the @'s I get no errors

Comment: After the `$sql` assignment, can you `var_dump($sql)` and share the output with us?

Comment: I get nothing at all even with var_dump($sql)

Comment: You wouldn't get an error from `var_dump($sql)`, you'd get the SQL statement displayed in the returned page.  I want to see the contents of the `$sql` variable.

Comment: @Josepth Vodary: if you really do get nothing from `var_dump($sql);`, this means you've made a loose typing error on the variable `$send`.  Can you explain?  Can you add in there a closing `else` statement to catch the unexpected?

Comment: Yeah, before the `if` statement at the top, put `var_dump($send)` and lets see what's happening.  Might be worth putting `var_dump($user_err)` there, too, while we debug this.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't give any errors because you've told PHP to ignore errors.  Remove the "@" from in front of all the mysql function calls, you'll get the errors.

Answer (score 1):

The "@" symbol in front of php mysql function suppresses any errors.
Remove it and then you'll see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the risks you take using variable expansion inside strings.

This statement:

```
$sql = "UPDATE $table_name SET curbid = '$_POST[price]', nbids = '$totalnbid' WHERE aucname = '$auc' ";
```

... would be better written as:

```
$sql = "UPDATE ".$table_name." SET curbid = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price'])."', nbids = '".mysql_real_escape_string($totalnbid)."' WHERE aucname = '".mysql_real_escape_string($auc)."' ";
```

Comment: changing that does nothing, and still no errors

Comment: Then you need to start putting debugging prints in so you can see what it thinks it's doing.

Comment: While it's true that `mysql_real_escape_string()` needs to be used on these variables before handing them to `mysql_query()`, double-quoted string interpolation is not risky.  It is a valuable feature of PHP that if used & understood properly offers superior readability and is far less error prone than dozens of concatenations & the quoting needed to make them happen.

Comment: @Michael, we will just have to differ on the value and readability of variable expansion in PHP.